# URL for a reply window to a specific Gmail message

Tags: javascript, gmail

Is there a URL that will navigate to a specific Gmail message with the reply window open?

For example, `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new` will navigate to the inbox with a compose window open. I'm looking for a URL that will do this, but for replying to a specific message.

Answer (score 0):

---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: 
Date: 20-Nov-2018 2:41 pm
Subject: Successful Registration for UP POLICE 2018B
To: <1978sanjayp@gmail.com>
Cc:

Dear Applicant,

You have successfully registered for UP POLICE 2018B. Below are the credentials.

Application Sequence No :: 100117522

Password: DOB in DDMMYYYY Format